# How to resolve security finding (CVE-2016-9606) in Quarkus RESTEasy?

Tags: security, resteasy, quarkus

In my application I use the quarkus framework with the RESTEasy extension. The current version contains the [CVE-2016-9606](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2016-9606).
Description of this CVE:

> JBoss RESTEasy before version 3.1.2 could be forced into parsing a
> request with YamlProvider, resulting in unmarshalling of potentially
> untrusted data which could allow an attacker to execute arbitrary code
> with RESTEasy application permissions.

How to update to a version after 3.1.2 to resolve the issue?

**Update 17.01.2022:**
This was only a problem with quarkus version <=2.2. I tested today with 2.6.2.Final and didn't get this security finding.

Comment: I'm running Quarkus version 2.2.3 and I can see RESTeasy is 4.7.0. Are you really sure you are using "the current version"? Please mention your version as well.

Comment: I don't think any version of Quarkus used RESTEasy 3.x. I don't see how this CVE would be an issue in Quarkus.